# Display contents of the 4 column horizontally in a 8/4 configuration in Twiiter Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a test page that has a Container within which there are two columns in an 8/4 configuration. What I want is for the 4 to slide under the eight in a row rather than a column when the viewport is reduced.

So what I'm looking for is for the column on the right to display vertically at a large viewport and horizontally in a mid viewport.

Here's a before and after image, and below is the code:

[image]

```
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="col-md-8 column">
            <div class="row clearfix">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 column">
                    <p>
                        Ad simul sensibus per, vel brute summo an, eam harum viderer definiebas ne. Falli
                        graeco sea cu. Est dolores lobortis omittantur ei, exerci scriptorem no vim. Diam
                        tamquam adolescens est id, partem eleifend in pro.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 column">
                    <p>
                        Ad simul sensibus per, vel brute summo an, eam harum viderer definiebas ne. Falli
                        graeco sea cu. Est dolores lobortis omittantur ei, exerci scriptorem no vim. Diam
                        tamquam adolescens est id, partem eleifend in pro.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 column">
                    <p>
                        Ad simul sensibus per, vel brute summo an, eam harum viderer definiebas ne. Falli
                        graeco sea cu. Est dolores lobortis omittantur ei, exerci scriptorem no vim. Diam
                        tamquam adolescens est id, partem eleifend in pro.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 column">
                    <p>
                        Ad simul sensibus per, vel brute summo an, eam harum viderer definiebas ne. Falli
                        graeco sea cu. Est dolores lobortis omittantur ei, exerci scriptorem no vim. Diam
                        tamquam adolescens est id, partem eleifend in pro.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 column">
                    <p>
                        Ad simul sensibus per, vel brute summo an, eam harum viderer definiebas ne. Falli
                        graeco sea cu. Est dolores lobortis omittantur ei, exerci scriptorem no vim. Diam
                        tamquam adolescens est id, partem eleifend in pro.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 column">
                    <p>
                        Ad simul sensibus per, vel brute summo an, eam harum viderer definiebas ne. Falli
                        graeco sea cu. Est dolores lobortis omittantur ei, exerci scriptorem no vim. Diam
                        tamquam adolescens est id, partem eleifend in pro.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 column">

            <div>
                <p>
                    R2 Ad simul sensibus per, vel brute summo an, eam harum viderer definiebas ne. Falli
                    graeco sea cu. Est dolores lobortis omittantur ei, exerci scriptorem no vim. Diam
                    tamquam adolescens est id, partem eleifend in pro.</p>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div>
                <p>
                    R3 Ad simul sensibus per, vel brute summo an, eam harum viderer definiebas ne. Falli
                    graeco sea cu. Est dolores lobortis omittantur ei, exerci scriptorem no vim. Diam
                    tamquam adolescens est id, partem eleifend in pro.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide a visual of what you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

After "div class=col-md-4" (the right column) have "div class=row clearfix" followed by "div class="col-lg-12 column col-md-12 column col-sm-4 column"

The first and second ones say "when the viewport is large display as a vertical column"  the third one says "when the viewport is small display as a horizontal column (a row)"

Thanks to Fabio for making me understand what these classes are actually saying.